# SSL crashes periodically caused by certificate server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS

Tags: windows, wcf, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to install a self-host WCF service on a server with Windows Server 2012.
I was following these steps:

1. import my pfx file with mmc
2. run "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:49000 certhash=e09280ded2322eb858b38b3250e1a488f797b269 appid={4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}"
3. install my service and start it

At first it works well. But after a few hours the ssl crashes and I can only get error msg at client as below

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
>   Additional information: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://servername:49000/WCFServiceName. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

run "netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:49000"
and delete the imported pfx and then redo step1 and 2 can make ssl works again, but the problem will still appears in a few hours.

It's definitely not the SecurityProtocol problem, for I have already tried adding

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

before request. And both server and client uses .Net Framework 4.5.2

I've tried "netsh http show sslcert", and got below result:

```
    IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:49000
    Certificate Hash             : e09280ded2322eb858b38b3250e1a488f797b269
    Application ID               : {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
    Certificate Store Name       : My
    Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Enabled
    Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
    Usage Check                  : Enabled
    Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
    URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
    Ctl Identifier               : (null)
    Ctl Store Name               : (null)
    DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
    Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
```

I've tried delete the sslcert binding on port 49000 and created an empty website binding to port 49000 in IIS and make my service listening to that port then. It works the first time and lasted for about a week before the same error pops out.

Where should I begin to locate and solve this wired problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, we should ensure that the certificate private key could be accessed by WCF. The Network Service account (or Everyone account) should be added in the certificate READ/Writer group, then we run the application (windows service, or console?) with corresponding account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-make-x-509-certificates-accessible-to-wcf
Second, as you know, TLS version need OS and Dotnetframework support, the default protocol version is ssl3.0/tls1.0(auto-negotiate, could not be configured). We had better use the latest OS version and .netframework4.7. I think this may be the cause of unstable communications.
Please refer to the below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: The service is ran by System account and have fully access to read/write certs. The weird thing is every time I re-install the cert and re-add sslcert the service will work fine for hours and then the same error goes out at client end, while the service is still running on server and does not throw any exception

Comment: when the invocation crashed, we could check the state of binding the certificate to the port by using the below code. netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9090 Besides,try to update the .netframework version

Comment: I've tried the "netsh http show sslcert" command and compared it with another https port that works well. It turns out that for ipport=0.0.0.0:9090 it shows "Certificate Store Name : (null)" but for the one works well it shows " Certificate Store Name : My". This seems to be the only difference. How should I fix that?

Comment: I suggest that we install the certificate in local machine certificate store location instead of the current user. we could manage and view the certificate by using Certlm.msc command.

Comment: I've reinstalled the cert in local machine certificate store using mmc ran in Admin mode. And got a same result: I can access to my service first once after the cert is installed, but after a while(about 1 hour) the same error pops out. Updated the question with "netsh http show sslcert" result.

Comment: I would like that you post the configuration. please don't setup the SSL protocol version since the Dotnetframework version is low. I think we had better update the framework version, as the document mentioned.